# Spring depenency injection: required a single bean

Tags: spring, spring-data

I've two projects: `common` and `backoffice`.

- `common`: is a jar library **I'm not able to modify**.
- `backoffice`: is spring-boot service.

`common` is used as `backoffice` dependency.

On `common` project there's a generic DAO interface like this:

```
public interface ApplicationDao extends MongoRepository<Application, String> {
    Application findByCode(String code);   
}
```

In the same project, there's a class with this dependency:

```
@Autowired
public RepositoryDocumentAuthorizationManager(ApplicationDao appsDao) {...}
```

By other hand, in `backOffice` project, I've coded an `ApplicationBackOfficeDao` which extends `ApplicationDao`:

```
public interface ApplicationBackOfficeDao extends ApplicationDao {
    Optional<Application> getByName(String name);
}
```

When `backoffice` service is started I'm getting this exception message:

```
***************************
APPLICATION FAILED TO START
***************************

Description:

Parameter 1 of constructor in net.gencat.transversal.espaidoc.common.RepositoryDocumentAuthorizationManager required a single bean, but 2 were found:
        - applicationDao: defined in null
        - applicationBackOfficeDao: defined in null


Action:

Consider marking one of the beans as @Primary, updating the consumer to accept multiple beans, or using @Qualifier to identify the bean that should be consumed
```

It's telling me that `RepositoryDocumentAuthorizationManager` is not able to resolve its `ApplicationDao` dependency.

**The problem** is that I'm not able to add `@Primary` on `ApplicationDao`, since **I'm not able to modify `common` project**. Also, I'm not able to modify `RepositoryDocumentAuthorizationManager` since it's in `common` project.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

try with this :

1. `applicationBackOfficeDao` bean is in your spring config project you can make it `@Primary` or use `@Qualifier`
2. In your `application.properties` add the following property

> spring.main.allow-bean-definition-overriding=true